# AspNetCore.Proxy certificate validation handler

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, httpclient

AspNetCore.Proxy creates an `httpClient` instance like this:

```
var httpClient = context.RequestServices
    .GetService<IHttpClientFactory>()
    .CreateClient(options?.HttpClientName ?? Helpers.HttpProxyClientName);
```

Without modifying this library, is it possible within the DI services setup to create this `httpClient` instance with a custom handler that ignores certificate warnings?

This code doesn't work:

```
builder.Services.AddHttpClient(string.Empty, c => { })
    .ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() =>
    {
        return new HttpClientHandler
        {
            ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true
        };
    });
```

Comment: The certificate warning is coming from the proxy.  You can disable using the proxy.  The ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback is used to specify a particular certificate to be used, not to disable the warning.

Comment: @jdweng ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback  is used to implement custom certificate validation which can include ignoring errors and returning `valid == true` in the instance of certain errors.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was to override the `IHttpClientFactory` in the end:

```
public class MyHttpClientFactory : IHttpClientFactory
{
    public HttpClient CreateClient(string name)
    {
        var clientHandler = new HttpClientHandler
        {
            ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => { return true; }
        };
        return new HttpClient(clientHandler);
    }
}
```

and to register with the DI service container:

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IHttpClientFactory>(new MyHttpClientFactory());
```